# What's the purpose of `var _ db.DB = (*DB)(nil)` (from leveldb-go)?

Tags: go

I'm afraid I don't think it is useful. But code like this from google must have it's reason.

`var _ db.DB = (*DB)(nil)`

It is from package [`code.google.com/p/leveldb-go`](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb-go/source/browse/leveldb/leveldb.go).

Please tell me the purpose of this.

Comment: @DarshanComputing: thanks! It should be noted that `db.DB` and `DB` are different interfaces, despite confusingly similar names.

Comment: I see. The answers from linked page explain it quite well. It is a really handy way to ensure or check `*DB` is implemet to `db.DB`.